# Cannot set property X of undefined - programatically created element

Tags: javascript

I am working on a class to create a fairly complex custom element. I want to be able to define element attributes (mainly CSS) as I am creating the elements. I came up with the below function to quickly set attrs for me given an input array:

```
// Sample array structure of apply_settings
//var _button_div =   {
//    syle    :   {
//        position:   'absolute',
//        padding :   '2px',
//        right   :   0,
//        top     :   0
//    }
//};
function __apply_settings(__el,apply_settings){
    try{
        for(settingKey in apply_settings){
            __setting = apply_settings[settingKey];
            if(typeof(__setting)=='string'){
                __el[settingKey] = __setting;
            }else{
                for(i in __setting){
                    __el[settingKey][i] = apply_settings[settingKey][i];
                } 
            }
        }
    }catch(ex){
        alert(ex + "   " + __el);
    }
}
```

The function works fine except here:

```
function __draw_top(){
    var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var buttonDiv = document.createElement('div');
    __apply_settings(containerDiv,this.settings.top_bar);
    if(global_settings.show_x)
        buttonDiv.appendChild(__create_img(global_settings.images.close));
    containerDiv.appendChild(buttonDiv);
    __apply_settings(buttonDiv,this.settings.button_div);
    return containerDiv;
}
```

The specific section that is failing is `__apply_settings(buttonDiv,this.settings.button_div);` with the error "Cannot set property 'position' of undefined". So naturally, I am assuming that buttonDiv is undefined.. I put `alert(ex + "   " + __el);` in __apply_settings() to verify what I was working with. Surprisingly enough, the element is a div. Is there any reason why this function would be working for containerDiv and not buttonDiv? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

{EDIT}
http://jsfiddle.net/Us8Zw/2/

Comment: Why can't you use `css({...})` ? _".css(map )
map A map of property-value pairs to set."_

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please :)

Comment: @gdoron no mention of jQuery here

Comment: @WickyNilliams. ohhh, then Why can't you use jQuery...? `:)`

Comment: It does make me wonder why anyone woulnd't lean on a framework for assistance in menial tasks like this. But it's hard to know people's requirements and until there is a mention of jQuery we have to assume it's not available :(

Comment: I'm not a fan of importing libraries when it is not necessary (not avail here either). I went ahead and rigged up the jsfiddle using the relevant portions of code. Sorry for not doing that in the first place :)  http://jsfiddle.net/Us8Zw/2/

Comment: Instead of the two underlines I personally prefer five dollar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a typo here:

```
var _button_div =   {
    syle    :   { //<--- here
        position:   'absolute',
        padding :   '2px',
        right   :   0,
        top     :   0
    }
};
```

If you correct it to `style`, it works fine; http://jsfiddle.net/Us8Zw/3/

I'd also advise you to try and follow a well known style guide (rather than seemingly making up your own); your code is quite hard to read at the moment. One I recommend is the [Crockford Style Guide](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: Wow...you know when you've been looking at code for too long when you beat your head on a table over something so incredibly simple! I believe it is time for a break, thank you for your assistance/spell checking :P

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @bfavaretto: Apparently I VtC'd aggesss ago when the question was asked (which has now aged away), and I'm not allowed to cast another close vote :(.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Matt. If you want to help cleaning up other similar questions, visit [the closing room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25318/the-closing-room).